# adding fade in and fade out when mouseover

Tags: javascript, fadein, fadeout

okay i know this question has been asked before but i can't understand a thing
i can html but i have no idea of javascript
http://axy-david.net23.net/java/1.html
i want the panels to have fade in and fade out whenever mouse cursor is over
also please keep in mind that i have no experience in javascript
the rest of the .js files are here:
http://axy-david.net23.net/java/

Comment: JavaScript and JScript are not exactly the same thing. JScript is the JavaScript implementation of Microsoft.

Comment: Nowadays, JScript is how Microsoft calls JavaScript in order to avoid patent things with Sun (now Oracle)..

Comment: thank you edited but whats the diffrence between oracle and microsofts javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding on the jQuery library and using the fadeIn and fadeOut functions. Examples and documentation here:
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

EDIT: More detailed step-by-step:
Download jQuery ( http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js ), save it with the rest of your js files, and add it in as an external JS file like your other ones.

Then you can use the function listed at that site.
Here's the first example they have:

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" />
With the element initially hidden, we can show it slowly:
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```

Comment: please keep in mind that i have no experience in javascript but it looks intresting

Comment: ye... ummmm i where do i add those lines in the 1.html? since the panels are in another script if you get what i mean

Comment: Sorry bro, I'm not going to write your code for you. Depending on what exactly you need (and I'm not even sure I'm understanding that), it'll be some combination of the jQuery functions mouseover()/mouseout(), fadeOut()/fadeIn(). Something like this jQuery("div.panel").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this).fadeOut();
});  may help, and you just need to put it in <script> tags somewhere in your script, generally I put it at the top or in an external file.